# SQL: Not being able to use column alias in where

Tags: sql, select, stored-procedures, alias

Given the following sql example procedure:

```
DECLARE @xmlvoucherSequenceList xml = '<?xml version="1.0"?><Voucher><Id Item1="6425"/></Voucher>'

select
    col.value('./@Item1','int') voucherSequence
    from @xmlvoucherSequenceList.nodes('/Voucher/Id') t(col) 
    where voucherSequence not in (
        ...
    )
```

I don't understand why "voucherSequence" alias in where appear underlined in red in the sql management studio editor with "Column voucherSequence not found".

If I comment the where part and run only the select, the voucherSequence clearly appears as the column name (alias).

The weird thing is if I replace the previous query by the next one:

```
select
    col.value('./@Item1','int') voucherSequence
    from @xmlvoucherSequenceList.nodes('/Voucher/Id') t(col) 
    where col.value('./@Item1','int') not in (
        ...
    )
```

The sql compiler won't complain and the query works fine, but I'd like to use the alias in where, that's why alias is for.

Comment: This is not allowed, as per the SQL *standard*.  Use a CTE, subquery, or lateral join instead.

Comment: Thanks @Gordon Linoff. Could you please give me an example?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code looks like SQL Server.  I would recommend:

```
select v.voucherSequence    
from @xmlvoucherSequenceList.nodes('/Voucher/Id') t(col) cross apply
     (values (t.col.value('./@Item1', 'int'))
     ) v(voucherSequence)
where v.voucherSequence not in (
    ...
)
```